# Can't use JSTL in JSP page, with project that includes juel-impl jar because of ClassCastException with ExpressionFactoryImpl

Tags: eclipse, jsp, maven, jstl

The error is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception      [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.el.ExpressionFactory
at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:180)
at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:107)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.<init>(PageInfo.java:79)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:110)
    .....
```

The project is using a war overlay, in which the overlaid project has the juel-impl jar, which is necessary for its use of shindig. Any way to use jstl in the child project jsp pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have two rivaling EL APIs in your class path, tomcat's and another one from your application. Your war file must not contain an `el-api.jar` or `juel-api.jar`. Make sure to exclude those dependencies.

Comment: ok, I excluded the el-api.jar, but it seems there are still some classpath loading issues. When running my jsp page, I get the following errors:

Comment: INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstUnary$Operator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1564) at org.apache.catalina..WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523) at de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.Parser.unary(Parser.java:573

Comment: as well as - with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstUnary$Operator

Comment: looks like the juel jar is still getting in the way of tomcats el/jstl support?

Comment: What are the versions of tomcat and JUEL you use?

Comment: Your JUEL implements EL 2.1. Tomcat 7 uses EL 2.2. You may need to replace the juel-impl jar with version 2.2.x or use Tomcat 6

Comment: Which version of Tomcat 7 are you using. There seems to be a bug in versions prior to 7.0.26 that causes wrong class loader to be used.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52998

Answer (score 1):

The Juel 2.1.3 jar is a combination of the following Jars juel-impl.jar, juel-spi.jar and  juel-api.jar. 
We had the same issue when we included juel 2.1.3 jar in the pom and deployed in tomcat 7.

The issue is resolved by removing Juel 2.1.3 from pom and by adding only juel-impl.

<dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

you need to also add
      <dependency>
    <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
    <artifactId>juel-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
      </dependency>

The juel 2.1.3 jar contains the javax/el interfaces and are also a part of jsp-api jar.

I hope this will help.